# I think I was treated unfairly during hiring process - should I file a complaint against an HR manager?

Tags: hiring-process, human-resources, hiring, complaint

I applied for a position at a company. The job ad of this position said that they have a 'flexible working' option. I have my necessity, so I have to work remotely for a year (but I didn't indicate my necessity in the initial application because they didn't allow me to submit any cover letter).

After waiting for a few weeks, I got a response from an HR of that company. She wanted to have a call with me to discuss the next step. I replied to her quickly, through the same email address she contacted me, that I was available for the call. However, I noted in the reply that due to my necessity, I might have to work remotely. I will completely understand if she would reject me because of that reason.

But then, nothing happened. No call, No further email response at all.

Then I sent another reply to the original email she sent to follow up. Nothing happened again. One week later, I sent another new email to ask her (politely) whether I was still in the process or not. And then, I finally got an email from her. **She said that she didn't receive any responses from me since my first reply, and the position I applied for had been offered to another candidate.**

Yes, I feel irritated. To be honest, I don't believe that she didn't receive my responses because she contacted me first. So when I replied to her, the chance that my response emails might fall in her 'junk mail' inbox should be very low. If she replied to me like 'Sorry, we could not accept applicants who want to work remotely' or something like that -- it would be ok! But to say 'I didn't receive any responses from you' and say easily that 'We already offered the position to another applicant' was so irresponsible.

[I already got the answer that I shouldn't file a complaint against her. I might think too less. Thank you so much for all of your suggestions.]

Comment: Why are you so sure your emails got through and she’s just a liar? Did you call? My father suddenly stopped receiving my emails because some server got put on a spam block list. His service provider was ‘helpfully’ trashing them and he had no idea. Spam filtering is dynamic and aggressive at companies these days thanks to the recent uptick in dangerous ransomware.

Comment: Because the latest email which I sent (and she already answered), and the previous follow up email has similar content. I just added a few sentences in latest email to introduce myself again (and say sorry for sending email repeatedly)

Comment: Content is not the only reason why emails get blocked, and servers get added to and dropped from spam block lists all the time. Spam block algorithms regularly block email that isn’t spam, then someone realizes too much is blocked and fixes it. The timing of her responses and content of your emails doesn’t prove much. What do you hope to accomplish by complaining to her boss even if she did overlook your emails and then lie about it?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I get your point. I don't expect to get the job now. I just wanna let them know that this kind of thing shouldn't be happened with anyone else in the future.

Comment: I’m sorry this happened to you, but it probably wasn’t the fault of the lady you were communicating with. You should ask if there’s some way to make sure your emails get through in the future. Maybe she can ask someone to try to find out what happened to them.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by complaining? It won't increase your chances on the other application you have running. Consider that 1) she has no incentive to lie to you, and 2) the company isn't going to launch a full scale investigation on what happened, let it rest.

Comment: "Should I file a complaint against her?"  What has she done other than tell you that she did not receive your responses to warrant filing a complaint?  Imagine if she simply 'believed' that you never sent any response and filed a complaint about you to HR claiming you are a liar and therefore un-hirable for any position in the company.

Comment: Also, if she has any message rules not properly set up in her mail client she can easily miss important emails.

Comment: If you file a complaint on scant evidence, if you consider people liars without knowing the details of what happened, you wave big red flags to whoever wants to hire you. You will land immediately on the "do not hire" list. You are not the only person in her inbox. Others are human, and have human problems, and make human mistakes, too.

Comment: I work for a company whose recruiter contacted me and then my e-mails would constantly end up in his spam box, even when I was just replying. It's unfortunate, but it does happen sometimes. I find it hard to believe that a recruiter purposefully ignoring you would take her time to answer you afterwards. She could have just kept on ignoring you.

Comment: What does "my necessity" mean here?

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not  file a complaint against her.   However, you should mention to her,  **calmly**, that you did email her, repeatedly, to follow up about this  job, and received no response, and that she should check her spam filters and/or trash bin to see if your messages got filtered.  Spam filters  work weirdly and are  not always correct, and weird things get filtered.  It's not always the recipient's fault that they "ignored" (didn't receive) a message that was sent, but it is their responsibility to  follow up and fix any issue that is pointed out to them.  So follow up, point out the issue, and she will (hopefully) fix her spam filter  issue or whatever caused you not  to get a response.  Then, if you are still interested in this company, you should  express interest in this new job posting that this recruiter mentioned  and follow up on that.

Another solution may also be, when you follow up with this recruiter to express interest in her new position, to ask her for an alternate method of communication, as her email filters may be broken.  She probably has a LinkedIn account or something similar where you can connect and chat if email isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

They have no obligation to email you, call you, interview you, consider your feelings, respect your time, or acknowledge you in any way. These things happen, for a variety of reasons.

Let it go. This isn't a battle that needs to be fought.